# "Error in if (!all(pars < 1e-06)) pars[pars < 1e-06] <- 0" error in a model with depmixS4

Tags: r, glm, model-fitting

## Problem

I want to run a latent class analysis with depmixS4 package in r. The problem appears while trying to fit a model with only one class (or state in depmixS4 package). When I try to adjust the model with a dataset of 6000 cases I get the following error. However, when the cases are 5000 there is no problem.

```
Error in if (!all(pars < 1e-06)) pars[pars < 1e-06] <- 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Where is the problem? Could someone help me understand why this error occurs?

## A reproducible example

**CASE A (n = 6000)**
The same case also occurs when it comes to aleatory variables. To have a reproducible example, first I generate a dataset (n = **6000**) with two random variables (a and b) with two possible values (0 and 1).

```r
library(depmixS4)
#> Loading required package: nnet
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: Rsolnp
a <- sample(0:1, size = 6000, replace = T)
b <- sample(0:1, size = 6000, replace = T)

foo_large <- data.frame(a,b)

set.seed(123)
mod1 <- mix(response = list(a~1, b~1),
            data=foo_large, # the dataset to use
            nstates=1, # the number of latent classes
            family=list(multinomial("identity"),multinomial("identity")))

fmod1 <- fit(mod1, verbose=TRUE)
#> Error in if (!all(pars < 1e-06)) pars[pars < 1e-06] <- 0: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**CASE B (n = 5000)** However, with a dataset (n = **5000**) with two random variables with the same characteristics as the previous ones, there is no error.

```r
library(depmixS4)
#> Loading required package: nnet
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: Rsolnp
c <- sample(0:1, size = 5000, replace = T)
d <- sample(0:1, size = 5000, replace = T)

foo_short <- data.frame(c,d)

set.seed(123)
mod1 <- mix(response = list(c~1, d~1),
            data=foo_short, # the dataset to use
            nstates=1, # the number of latent classes
            family=list(multinomial("identity"),multinomial("identity")))

fmod1 <- depmixS4::fit(mod1, verbose=TRUE)
#> iteration 0 logLik: -6928.943 
#> converged at iteration 1 with logLik: -6928.943
```

Comment: What's the reason to run the model with `nstates = 1`

Comment: The reason is to see the changes in the model between `nstates = 1` and `nstates = 2`

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging and the error seems due to the way depmixS4 provides random starting values to initialize the EM algorithm (it generates random probabilities for class membership with a Dirichlet distribution and the code we use to draw from this distribution doesn't work well for a 1-dimensional Dirichlet). We'll fix this in an upcoming release. For now, you can run the EM without random starting values by using:

```
fmod1 <- fit(mod1, emcontrol=em.control(random.start=FALSE), verbose=TRUE)
```

This works in both your examples.

Note that the issue is not due to the difference in the number of observations **(n=5000)** or **(n=6000)**. That the code converged for **(n=6000)** was a lucky coincidence of using `set.seed(123)`. After deleting this line you will most likely get the same error as for **(n=6000)**. The latter you can coincidently get working if you set `set.seed(1234)`.